# Mongo search results with facet counts

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, faceted-search, mgo

I am new to Mongo and I'm looking to implement a faceted search in Go using the mgo driver.  I need to get both the documents that match my query as well as the facet counts.

My current implementation is to perform a query to get the documents, then another query with the same parameters to get the facet counts, but that seems really inefficient.  Is there a good way to do this in a single step?

For example, if I have a Collection of books:

```
[{
  title: "Book One",
  author: "Author A",
  numPages: 20,
  type: "book"
},
{
  title: "Book Two",
  author: "Author B",
  numPages: 40,
  type: "book"
},
...
...
...
{
  title: "Magazine AA",
  author: "Author A",
  numPages: 10,
  type: "magazine"
}]
```

First I get the documents that match my query:

```
err = books.Find(bson.M{"$and": matches}).All(&results)
```

Then I repeat the query using the aggregate pipeline and $facet to get the facet counts:

```
err = Pipe([]bson.M{
    {"$match": bson.M{"$and": matches}},
    {"$facet": bson.M{
        "type":     []bson.M{bson.M{"$sortByCount": "$type"}},
        "author":   []bson.M{bson.M{"$sortByCount": "$author"}, 
    }},
}).All(&facets)
```

I've also seen $out which would let me write my results to a temporary collection, which I could then use to determine facet counts, but I don't know if that's any more efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a good way to do this in a single step?

Yes, you can use facet search to add the un-faceted result. For example:

```
pipeline := []bson.M{ 
                {"$match": bson.M{"type": bson.M{"$in": []string{"book", "magazine"}}}},
                {"$facet": bson.M{"type": []bson.M{{"$sortByCount":"$type"}}, 
                                  "author": []bson.M{{"$sortByCount":"$author"}},
                                  "unfaceted": []bson.M{{"$match": bson.M{} }},
                                 },
                           },
            }
err = collection.Pipe(pipeline).All(&resp)
```

The above `unfaceted` `$match` is without condition (empty), as the first `$match` stage would already filtered down to the desired subset of documents.

Which gives you the result below:

```
{
  "type": [
    {
      "_id": "book",
      "count": 2
    },
    {
      "_id": "magazine",
      "count": 1
    }
  ],
  "author": [
    {
      "_id": "Author A",
      "count": 2
    },
    {
      "_id": "Author B",
      "count": 1
    }
  ],
  "unfaceted": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId(".."),
      "title": "Magazine AA",
      "author": "Author A",
      "numPages": 10,
      "type": "magazine"
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId(".."),
      "title": "Book Two",
      "author": "Author B",
      "numPages": 40,
      "type": "book"
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId(".."),
      "title": "Book One",
      "author": "Author A",
      "numPages": 20,
      "type": "book"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now you can iterate through `unfaceted` section instead of sending a separate query. See also [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) for more examples and description of the operator.

Comment: Great!  Thank you very much.